# Copy constructor when adding an element to vector

Tags: c++, move, copy-constructor

When we create an object and assign it to a variable and then we want to add it to some container, let's say `std::vector`, two things happen:

- the constructor is called for creating an object earlier
- the copy constructor is called when doing `push_back`

When we don't need the object anymore, we can use `std::move`, to speed the process up. So let's say I have a code like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

class foo
{
public:
    int x;
    foo() {}
    foo(int bar) : x(bar) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo>> foos;
    auto n = std::make_shared<foo>(42);
    foos.push_back(std::move(n));
}
```

But what if I didn't define the variable? What if I just did:

```
foos.push_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42));
```

Is the copy constructor invoked then? Should I use `std::move`? (like `foos.push_back(std::move(std::make_shared<foo>(42)));`) I tried to check it under [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/), but I cannot see anything in the assembler mess. So is there a copy constructor invoked (so I would use `std::move` to eliminate that) or it is not, and should I leave it like this: `foos.push_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42));`?

Comment: Check out [`std::vector<T>::emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) if you want to avoid copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are not going to use it after creating you can directly add it directly ( cause it will construct the object in place)

```
foos.emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42));
```

(push_back will create a temporary & then copy it so extra copy)

Comment: So the way of avoiding `push_back`'s extra copy would be using `emplace_back`?

Comment: yes if you want create the object directly in your vector emplace_back is your friend

Comment: So `.emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42))` would be faster, right? And what about `std::move` then?

Comment: @dabljues _"And what about `std::move` then?"_ There's no need for calling it explicitly  it in that case.

Comment: But then `emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42))` - wouldn't `emplace_back` call `foo::(foo&)` constructor or something with this syntax?

Comment: you can check the benchmarks here:https://www.embeddeduse.com/2016/05/25/performance-gains-through-cpp11-move-semantics/

Comment: @dabljues I will call `foo(foo&&)` if it's available, which is a move, not a copy.

Comment: `push_back` has a `T&&` overload since c++11 so `emplace_back` won't really help in this case. They will essentially do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_shared<foo>(42)` is already a r-value, no need of `std::move`.

Both methods here are similar:

```
foos.push_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42));
foos.emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42));
```

`emplace_back` allows to construct in place, so, instead you might do

```
foos.emplace_back(new foo(42));
```

but I would avoid to use directly `new` for no real benefit, as move constructor is cheap.

For `std::vector<foo> v;`, you might compare

```
foos.push_back(foo(42));    // call extra move constructor
foos.emplace_back(foo(42)); // call extra move constructor
foos.emplace_back(42);      // only call foo(int).
```

Comment: And what if I use `emplace_back`? Is it faster in this situation? Or should I use it with `std::move`?

Comment: `emplace_back` would be useful for `std::vector<foo> foo2s; foo2s.emplace_back(42);`, to construct in place.

Comment: But cannot I just `emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>(42))`?

Comment: @dabljues `push_back` and `emplace_back` are equivalent in this case.